# apache spark mlib loading logistic regression model from http source

Tags: apache-spark, model, spark-streaming, apache-spark-mllib

i want have a model on an extern http source, that I want to load in my spark streaming application for prediction of incoming data. Since the data is coming from different producers, I have to load individual models, depending on the data.

Spark runs on DCOS-mesos cluster and the model is a folder with data and metadata and parquet files.
Load directly from http is not possible, it needs "file:..."

I tried to download them into "./testmodel/" path, it lands also in the sandbox, but is not loading in the model because of the wrong path with following exception: Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/mnt/mesos/sandbox/testmodel/metadata

```
def fileDownloader(url: String, filename: String) = {
  new URL(url) #> new File(filename) !!
}...

val modelFolder: File = new File("./testModel");
modelFolder.mkdir();
val modelDataFolder: File = new File("./testModel/data")
modelDataFolder.mkdir();
val modelMetaDataFolder: File = new File("./testModel/metadata");
modelMetaDataFolder.mkdir();


fileDownloader("http://extern-host.com/sparkmodel/testmodel/data/._SUCCESS.crc", "./testModel/data/._SUCCESS.crc");
fileDownloader("http://extern-host.com/sparkmodel/testmodel/data/.part-00000-beca47f5-4fa8-4af8-ba76-21be4e0c4763-c000.snappy.parquet.crc", "./testModel/data/.part-00000-beca47f5-4fa8-4af8-ba76-21be4e0c4763-c000.snappy.parquet.crc");
fileDownloader("http://extern-host.com/sparkmodel/testmodel/data/_SUCCESS", "./testModel/data/_SUCCESS");
fileDownloader("http://extern-host.com/sparkmodel/testmodel/data/part-00000-beca47f5-4fa8-4af8-ba76-21be4e0c4763-c000.snappy.parquet", "./testModel/data/part-00000-beca47f5-4fa8-4af8-ba76-21be4e0c4763-c000.snappy.parquet");

fileDownloader("http://extern-host.com/sparkmodel/testmodel/metadata/._SUCCESS.crc", "./testModel/metadata/._SUCCESS.crc");
fileDownloader("http://extern-host.com/sparkmodel/testmodel/metadata/.part-00000.crc", "./testModel/metadata/.part-00000.crc");
fileDownloader("http://extern-host.com/sparkmodel/testmodel/metadata/_SUCCESS", "./testModel/metadata/_SUCCESS");
fileDownloader("http://extern-host.com/sparkmodel/testmodel/metadata/part-00000", "./testModel/metadata/part-00000");

val model = LogisticRegressionModel.load(sc, "./testModel");
```

Thanks in advice

Comment: That happens because model should be placed on a distributed file system, as it is loaded using `DataFrameReader`. So downloading is only the first step, the second one should be moving it to storage that can be used by each machine. You could also place a local copy on each node (`SparkFiles`  or archives can do that).

Comment: Thank you, now I add the files and folders using 

sparkContext.add("http://...")

as result I have the model on each executor...but somehow I got 

WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, 192.168.0.20, executor 3): java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/tmp/spark-23f6d5c1-7c0d-48c0-b243-dbf5551b8228/userFiles-ca4025a5-9cae-4a4e-8518-c3d76cad06e8/testmodel/metadata/part-00000 does not exist

but it should be there, I tested using the new File().exists function :(

Comment: Maybe its not on every executer? How can i check stuff like this?